# How to use Cesium.Measure on CesiumJs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to activate the measure plugin on CesiumJs
On a local host.
The local host is running and the model is appearing but I am unable to get a measurability bar to appear.
The code is attached
I would love to get help :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Use correct character set. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <!-- Make the app on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>New York City</title>
    <!-- The Cesium library. -->
    <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.72/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <script src="./CesiumMeasurer.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.72/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href= "C:\Users\Yoni\Desktop\Cesium-1.73\Apps\Sandcastle\templates\bucket.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Style our app. -->
    
    

    <style>
        html, body, #cesiumContainer {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cesiumContainer"></div> 
           
    <script >
         Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJkNDIwOGFhZC05NGM1LTRmOGItOTVjMS1kZmZlNDFiNjc1MzciLCJpZCI6MzEwMzgsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhc3IiLCJnYyJdLCJpYXQiOjE1OTQ3NDAzMjZ9.2VC0njaqUn3Oy4BNOKW06q3qBEWYZlmicucRG5iVgAQ";

         var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
         

         var imageryLayer = viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(
         new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({ assetId: 148315 }));

         

         var scene = viewer.scene;
         

        viewer.zoomTo(imageryLayer);



        var measureWidget = new Cesium.Measure({
        container : 'cesiumContainer',
        scene : scene,
        units : new Cesium.MeasureUnits({
        distanceUnits : Cesium.DistanceUnits.METERS,
        areaUnits : Cesium.AreaUnits.SQUARE_METERS,
        volumeUnits : Cesium.VolumeUnits.CUBIC_FEET,
        angleUnits : Cesium.AngleUnits.DEGREES,
        slopeUnits : Cesium.AngleUnits.GRADE})
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi
I'm trying to activate the measure plugin on CesiumJs
On a local host.
The local host is running and the model is appearing but I am unable to get a measurability bar to appear.
The code is attached
I would love to get help :)

Comment: I added a link to an earlier version 
 https://medium.com/@wugis1219/cesium-measurement-plugin-a9733e532152

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way to use the `Measure` object in the CesiumJS API is to do the following three steps:

1. Import the `Measure.css` style sheet into your JavaScript code. You can use Webpack to do this, or whatever tool you feel most comfortable with.
2. Add the `measureContainer` div to your HTML code. This should look something like this: `<div id="measureContainer"></div>`.
3. Initialize the `Measure` object in your JavaScript code. This could be as simple as:

```js
var measureWidget = new Cesium.Measure({
     container : 'measureContainer',
     scene : scene,
     units : new Cesium.MeasureUnits({
         distanceUnits : Cesium.DistanceUnits.METERS,
         areaUnits : Cesium.AreaUnits.SQUARE_METERS,
         volumeUnits : Cesium.VolumeUnits.CUBIC_FEET,
         angleUnits : Cesium.AngleUnits.DEGREES,
         slopeUnits : Cesium.AngleUnits.GRADE
     })
});
```

A few notes on the code that you provided:

- The `Measure` object is part of Cesium ion SDK, not CesiumJS. While CesiumJS is free and open-source, Cesium ion SDK is not.
- It does not look like you are importing `Measure.css` as outlined above in step 1.
- I recommend moving most of your JavaScript code into a separate JavaScript file.